# JQuery TR Not being deleted on AJAX reload

Tags: jquery

The synchChecks() function is failing to delete the table row, but the JQuery selector reference to the TR seems to be correct. What could cause this? I'm applying the logic on AJAX reload, as expected, the selected TR's are checked, but the click fails and no errors are thrown.

```
    $(function () {

        $(".pagination li").css("cursor","pointer")
        $('.pagination').on('click', 'li', function () {
            $('.pagination li').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });


        $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divVendors').html(result);
                    applyVendorLogic();
                    synchChecks();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function applyVendorLogic() {
        $("#tblVendorSelect").on('click', '.chkVendor', function () {

            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {

                var $trid = "xtr" + $(this).parent().parent().prop("id");
                var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var $ts = $tr.clone();
                $ts.attr("id", $trid);

                $ts.on('click', '.chkVendor', function () {
                    $("#vendorSelection #" + $ts.attr("id")).remove();
                })

                $tr.on('click', '.chkVendor', function () {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
                        $("#vendorSelection #" + $ts.attr("id")).remove();
                    }
                })

                $("#vendorSelection").append($ts);

            }

        });
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function synchChecks() {

        $("#vendorSelection .chkVendor").each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                $("#tblVendorSelect #" + $(this).attr("id")).prop("checked", true);
                $("#tblVendorSelect").on('click',"#" + $(this).attr("id"),function () {

                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
                        $("#vendorSelection #x" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id")).remove();
                    }
                })
            }
        });

    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

[appplyVendorLogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQZLR.png)
[synchChecks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ludup.png)

Now I an successfully navigate between pages and maintain the synchronization. If one box is checked, the other is as well. if it is unchecked, the row is removed and the check box in the selection table is also unchecked.

Comment: Can't you remove $ts directly instead of using its ID?

Comment: My apologies. I probably wasn't clear enough. The synchChecks() function is the one that isn't working, specifically the portion of code:

    $("#tblVendorSelect").on('click',"#" + $(this).attr("id"),function () {

                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
                        $("#vendorSelection #x" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id")).remove();
                    }
                })

Comment: Do you not clone the $tr into $ts then erase the original and append the new clone back in its place - net effect no apparent change?

Comment: The desired behavior is such that when the check box is unchecked, the corresponding record in the other table vendorSelection is removed.

Comment: Because the page is being loaded via AJAX, the logic has to be reapplied. Every other piece of code is fully functional. The only portion of the code that has me stumped is:

Comment: $("#vendorSelection #x" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id")).remove();

Comment: If I'm reading you right you have two tables with linked records, which both have the same `id`.. That's not allowed, `id` tags should be unique, directly selecting only one unique element. If you have two records with the same `id`, doesn't matter where they are on the page, your code will/should have trouble knowing which one to remove. I don't know if fixing that will solve your problem, jQuery might be forgiving enough, but that doesn't make it right... Also, `prop("id")` should be `attr("id")` (`$trid`), and there's a couple of things that aren't written in the most efficient way

Comment: As for that line in your last comment: are you sure the `x` isn't a typo?

Comment: I was able to get it working guys. I'm not able to post an answer, because of my reputation score and that fact I'm now on here. So, I'll add the pictures.

Comment: I also can't edit my comments. says something about not having the right.

Comment: See screenshots. Thanks for the help.

Comment: assigning click events inside of click events is always a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting, can you explain? I'm eager to understand why. I'm not a JQuery expert, though I've been coding in javascript for years. I'm also a huge fan of best practice. So, please feel free to elaborate more.